# Animate cc response array con resultado null php ajax y javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, web

tengo este codigo en php y javascript para el Aimate cc pero no recoge los datos del array por json. He probado con un array normal y en console si lo ve pero con este tipo de array falla. Todo lo demas como llamada a la base de datos ... esta verificado que funciona y con un json simple tambien.

PHP leer2.php

```
include("conex.php");

$ssql = "SELECT * FROM proves WHERE nom LIKE 'david'";
$p=mysqli_query($mysqli, $ssql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($p)) {
$nom = $row['nom'];
$descrip = $row['descrip'];
$numero = $row['cant'];

$return_arr = array("nom" => $nom,
"descrip" => $descrip,
"numero" => $numero);

}

//$directors = array( "Alfred Hitchcock", "Stanley Kubrick", "Martin Scorsese", "Fritz Lang" );
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

---

SCRIPT DE ANIMATE

```
var root = this;

function ono(){

var ev = "david";
$.ajax({
url:'leer2.php',
dataType:'json',
type:'post',
data:{ev:ev},
success: function(resp){
var nom = resp.nom;
var descrip = resp.descrip;
var numero = parseInt(resp.numero);
root.textos.dave_te.text = nom + descrip + numero;

console.log(resp);
}
});
}
ono();
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás enviando solo un arreglo con las propiedades `nom`, `descrip` y `numero`, porque en cada iteración del ciclo sobrescribes `$return_arr`. No importa cuántos registros existan, siempre se enviará el último como un único objeto:

```
{nom: 'Nombre del último registro', descrip: 'Descripción del último', numero: 123}
```

Tu petición AJAX *debería* recibir un arreglo de objetos como:

```
[
    {nom: 'Nombre 1', descrip: 'Descripción 1', numero: 123},
    {nom: 'Nombre 2', descrip: 'Descripción 2', numero: 123},
    {nom: 'Nombre X', descrip: 'Descripción X', numero: 123},
]
```

El error que puede estar pasando es que estás definiendo la variable `$return_arr` dentro del ciclo y, cuando no se encontraron resultados, no existe, por lo que `json_encode($return_arr)` devuelve un error.

Necesitas:

- Ajustar la consulta, porque `nom LIKE 'david'` es exactamente lo mismo que `nom = 'david'` por la falta de comodines `%`. Mejorando el LIKE:

  - Para buscar el nombre al inicio, se usa `david%`
  - Para buscar al final: `%david`
  - Para buscar en cualquier posición: `%david%`
- Inicializar el arreglo antes del ciclo, ya sea con `$return_arr = array();` o, simplificado `$return_arr = [];`
- Agregar los elementos en cada iteración, ya sea con `array_push($return_arr, $nuevo_elemento);` o, mejor aún, sin usar función y agregando corchetes a la variable `$return_arr[] = $nuevo_elemento;`

```
include("conex.php");

$ssql = "SELECT * FROM proves WHERE nom LIKE '%david%'";
$p=mysqli_query($mysqli, $ssql);

// Inicializar arreglo, para agregar elementos dentro del ciclo
// También evitará errores al final, en caso de que no haya resultados
$return_arr = [];
// Recorrer resultados
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($p)) {
    $nom = $row['nom'];
    $descrip = $row['descrip'];
    $numero = $row['cant'];

    // Agregar elemento al arreglo
    $return_arr[] = [
        "nom" => $nom,
        "descrip" => $descrip,
        "numero" => $numero
    ];
}

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Luego, en tu petición AJAX, necesitas validar que se recibieron datos y, solo entonces, tratar de mostrarlos:

```
var root = this;

function ono() {
    var ev = "david";
    $.ajax({
        url:'leer2.php',
        dataType:'json',
        type:'post',
        data:{ev:ev},
        success: function(resp) {
            // Ver datos recibidos
            console.log(resp);
            // Borrar contenido inicial
            root.textos.dave_te.text = '';
            // Hay resultados?
            if(resp.length > 0) {
                // Sí hay resultados, se deben recorrer
                resp.forEach(item => {
                    let nom = item.nom;
                    let descrip = item.descrip;
                    let numero = parseInt(item.numero);
                    // Agregar contenido usando plantillas de texto
                    root.textos.dave_te.text += `<div>
                       Nombre: ${nom}<br>
                       Descripción: ${descrip}<br>
                       Número: ${num}
                    </div>`;
                });
            } else {
                // Actualizar contenido
                root.textos.dave_te.text = 'No se encontraron resultados';
            }
        }
    });
}
ono();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo he copiado y publicado pero sale "No se encontraron resultados". Entiendo tu planteamiento pero no entiendo porque sale el error ,ya que en la BD si hay datos.

Comment: Ejecuta la consulta en PHPMyAdmin, seguramente ahí podrás ver lo que está pasando.

Comment: Lo he conseguido, tu código funciona perfecto. Únicamente no me maqueta los <div> y <br> pero no hay problema ya creare variables de las respuestas y lo maqueto a mi manera. Muchísimas gracias.